# Custom List Sort by multiple conditions

Tags: c#, list, sorting, .net-2.0

I have a class with a string field that I want to sort on by using multiple conditions.

The class in question

```
class Items
{
    public string ItemType {get; set;}
    public string Code {get; set;}

    // other members elided

    public Items(string _IT, string _Cd)
    {
        ItemType = _IT;
        Code = _Cd;
    }
}
```

Using the class

```
List<Items> lstItemCol = new List<Items>();

lstItemCol.Add(new Items("EE", "12345"));
lstItemCol.Add(new Items("WW", "5881"));
lstItemCol.Add(new Items("LLL", "215458"));
lstItemCol.Add(new Items("WW", "789"));
lstItemCol.Add(new Items("EE", "582"));
```

What I want to do is sort the list so the items are Ordered by EE followed by WW then LLL

Output order should be :

```
"EE", "582"
"EE", "12345"
"WW", "5881"
"WW", "789"
"LLL", "215458"
```

I cannot think of an elegant way to do this other then adding another field to the class (`sortOrder`) and sort on this: I would prefer to avoid that and just sort on ItemType?

Comment: Check out the overloads of `List<T>.Sort()`. Use a custom comparison.

Comment: Would you be happy enough creating a *new* list which is sorted in the way you want? If so, LINQ is definitely the way to go. Otherwise, a custom comparison shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: Your sort order isn't clear. Particularly, how do you sort items when ItemType is equal

Comment: You can try this :   lstItemCol.Sort((x, y) => x.ItemType != y.ItemType ? x.ItemType.CompareTo(y.ItemType) : x.Code.CompareTo(y.Code));

Comment: Should have said i am using .Net 2.0 so i can't use LINQ

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of implementing this in reusable and clean way.

1. Implement [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) on the Item
2. Create you own Item comparer and use it as parameter to order by of linq.

PS: I would also recommend using singular form for class name Item not plural form Items. Items usually refers to collections.

PPS: I also used [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to demonstrate implementation.

```
void Main()
{
    var lstItemCol = new List<Item>();

    lstItemCol.Add(new Item("EE", "12345"));
    lstItemCol.Add(new Item("WW", "5881"));
    lstItemCol.Add(new Item("LLL", "215458"));
    lstItemCol.Add(new Item("WW", "789"));
    lstItemCol.Add(new Item("EE", "582"));

    lstItemCol.OrderBy(ic => ic).Dump();
    lstItemCol.OrderBy(ic => ic, new ItemComparer()).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

class Item : IComparable<Item>, IComparable
{
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    // other members elided

    public Item(string _IT, string _Cd)
    {
        ItemType = _IT;
        Code = _Cd;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Item other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        var result = ItemType.Length.CompareTo(other.ItemType.Length);
        if (result == 0) result = ItemType.CompareTo(other.ItemType);
        if (result == 0) result = Code.Length.CompareTo(other.Code.Length);
        if (result == 0) result = Code.CompareTo(other.Code);
        return result;
    }
    int IComparable.CompareTo(object other)
    {
        return CompareTo(other as Item);
    }
}

sealed class ItemComparer : FComparer<Item>
{
    private static readonly Func<Item, Item, int> _comparer = (v1, v2) =>
    {
        var result = v1.ItemType.Length.CompareTo(v2.ItemType.Length);
        if (result == 0) result = v1.ItemType.CompareTo(v2.ItemType);
        if (result == 0) result = v1.Code.Length.CompareTo(v2.Code.Length);
        if (result == 0) result = v1.Code.CompareTo(v2.Code);
        return result;
    };

    public ItemComparer()
        :base(_comparer)
    { }
}

abstract class FComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, int> _comparer;

    protected FComparer(Func<T, T, int> comparer)
    { _comparer = comparer; }

    public int Compare(T v1, T v2)
    {
        return _comparer(v1, v2);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note this you can also use .Sort on the list since Item implemented IComparable. It will work as desired without linq.